# Evaluate Poker HandRange A vs. Poker HandRange B

Tags: algorithm, poker

I have this problem: I want to know how often a player holding a portfolio of poker hands beats another player holding a different portfolio of poker hands.

Each hand in a portfolio is given a weight (i.e. a likelihood).  Each hand in a portfolio also knows it's own "strength".  This effectively means all cards have been dealt.  So please assume no more cards need to be dealt.

The reason this problem is annoying is because of duplicate card problems.  For example, if I pick a random holding from each player's portfolio I must check that these holdings don't share a card -- obviously both plays can't be dealt the same card.

I want to do this quickly so that I can make many different RangeA vs RangeB comparisions per second.  I have a solution, but I won't talk about it yet because I don't want to taint any responces.

-- For an Example --
Given a 5 card board of "Ah 3c 8c Td Jh":
HandRangeA = {{"As Ac", 2.5%}, {"As Ad", 2.5%}, {"Ac Kc", 5%}....}
HandRangeB = {{"As Ac", 7.5%}, {"As Ad", 7.5%}, {"Ac Kc", 5%}....}
(Each HandRange contains all possible holding that don't use a "board card")

Goal :: compute the probaility HandRangeA beats HandRangeB

Comment: Since you seem to provide comments on everything that it isn't why don't you just tell us what it is?

Comment: @Woot4Moo -- Because when you play too much poker you get in the habit of getting an answer to a "What would you do?" question BEFORE you say what you did and what the result was (this helps ensure that your opinion doesn't put too much bias on the responses you recieve)(withholding my approach isn't meant to be Jerk-like)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you please write an example input and corresponding output.

Comment: Is it important to compute how often HandRange A beats HandRange B?

You could ignore your issue of multiple cards if you opted for an expected value instead of a win percentage.

This way you could ignore the cases where cards are identical, and assume they are pushes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
probWin = 0
For Each HandA in RangeA
  probA = getProbability(HandA)
  For Each HandB in RangeB
    probB = getConditionalProbability(HandB, HandA)
    probWin += probA * probB * getProbabilityADefeatsB(HandA, HandB)
```

You need to consider conditional probability, because given HandA is As Ac, there is no longer a 7.5% chance that HandB is As Ac (in fact, there is a 0% chance of that).  So you are taking the probability of A having a particular hand multiplied by the probability of B having a particular hand, given what A has, multiplied by the probability of A's hand beating B's hand.  That should give you the probability of A having that hand against that particular hand of B's and winning.  Iterating over all such pairs should give the desired result I think.

Since the approach is exhaustive, there is no need for any sort of Monte Carlo simulation.  Of course this will be O(n^2) where n is the number of possible hands, but n here is relatively small.

EDIT:
I should note that since you are referring to the case where all cards have been dealt, the getProbabilityADefeatsB() function would return either 1 or 0.  Also, getConditionalProbability() will either be exactly 0 (because the hands share a card) or simply what your regular weight was.  It would be more complicated if the hands were less specific (if HandA is AA then HandB could be a different flavor of AA, but it is less likely).

Comment: FWIW, I tried something very similar to this (outright enumeration).

Comment: Then what was the problem with that implementation?

Comment: There wasn't a huge problem, but I've seen SO offer slick answers to questions, I was hoping to see an answers I didn't think of.  (My version switches between MonteCarlo and enumeration depending on the number of hands in the input ranges HandRangeA)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some software that did this via monte carlo.  That means I ran both hands to completion, 1000 times with random boards that could arrive given the situation, and counted wins and losses.  It was surprisingly accurate.

Since I was doing it for texas holdem, I would do the same thing after the (1) deal, (2) flop, 3 (turn) so the player could see how their percentages changed given the board.

I really should have finished that software.  But I stopped playing poker online....

Comment: Please assume no more cards need to be dealt, Solving this problem when more cards are coming is drastically different from solving the problem when the board is complete.

Comment: you can still use monte carlo, just don't calculate what you dont want to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

I think Andrew Prock is considered the expert here; check out the discussion [here](http://www.pokerstove.com/analysis/zealots.php), and links therein.

Comment: I'm well aware of PokerStove.  PokerStove does not allow for Weighted ranges.

Comment: The ideas still apply. You have a range which is a probability distribution on a variety of hands. You draw from these ranges according to the specified distributions. Now you apply Prock's ideas to evaluate the win % of the hands against each other. Sum accordingly.

Comment: Prock's idea applies when there are future cards.  This does not apply here because all the cards are already dealt.